# Cast field to bit 0 if null and bit 1 if not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use this method to check if a row is foreign keyed in another table.

```sql
select
  personID,
  name,
  (
    /* CAST THIS PART TO BIT return 1 if field is found, 0 if not */
    select top 1 parents.personID
    from parents
    where parents.personID=persons.personID

  ) as inUse
from persons
```

Is it possible to do as I commented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `exists` and `case` expression:

```
select personID
     , name
     , case when exists ( select *
                          from parents
                          where parents.personID=persons.personID) then 1 else 0 end as inUse
from persons
```

Or just perform a `left join`:

```
select distinct pe.personID
     , pe.name
     , case when pa.personID is null then 0 else 1 end as inUse
from persons pe
left join parents pa on pa.personID = pe.personID
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use a LEFT OUTER JOIN and test the result.

It would look something like this:

```
select
  personID,
  name,
  case when parents.personID is null then 0 else 1 end as 'HasAParent'
from persons
left outer join parents
on parents.personID=persons.personID
```

This also allows you to use the other fields of the Parents table in your select (eg show the parents name, if a parent does exist).